# git --version command returns different result from what's actually installed

Tags: git, terminal, homebrew

Tried to update my git with homebrew and I encountered this problem:

```
MBP:GitHub_Tutorial nasdas$ brew install git
Warning: git 2.21.0 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 2.21.0, run `brew reinstall git`
MBP:GitHub_Tutorial nasdas$ git --version
git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)
```

Comment: Run `hash -r` and then `which git`. What is the output?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/git

Comment: more interestingly, after running hash -r, it now shows the correct version of git when i run git --version

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably you have *both* versions installed, independent of each other.

Use `type git` or `which git` to see which one you're running.  It's probably `/usr/bin/git`.  The brew-installed one is probably `/usr/local/bin/git`.  Change your `$PATH` (or `$path` or whatever your shell uses) to put `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` so that `git` will run the new one instead of the old one, or use `/usr/local/bin/git` to run the new one.

(And, as [Greg Bacon notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54871498/git-version-command-returns-different-result-from-whats-actually-installed/54871609#comment96513542_54871498), note that you might have to run `hash -r` in various shells to get them to check again after installing something in `/usr/local/bin`, if they've already decided that `git` means `/usr/bin/git` even though `$PATH` has `/usr/local/bin` earlier.  In csh/tcsh this is `rehash` instead of `hash -r`.)

(It turns out to have been the hash issue—your shell decided, earlier, that `git` meant the old one.  Logging in again also clears this sort of thing up, but that's a pain!)

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying! What exactly is '$PATH' and I am assuming, brew is installing packages on my local user account instead of globally? As you can see I am still very new to shell commands, so I am happy to learn more

Comment: `$PATH` is a shell variable *and* an environment variable (shells tend to mix the two together, for now it suffices to know it's both) that the shell uses to decide *how* to run commands. That is, you enter a command like `gronk fleeble1 fleeble2`. The shell has no idea what that means: it just tries to find some executable program named `gronk` and pass it those two arguments, for *it* to figure out. But where will the shell find `gronk`? The answer is: it looks at each element of `$PATH`, one element at a time. [cont'd]

Comment: `$PATH` might be set to, for instance, `/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin`. So the shell would attempt to run `/usr/local/bin/gronk`, and that would probably fail. Then it would try `/bin/gronk` which probably also fails, and finally, `/usr/bin/gronk` which probably *also* fails, and then it gives up and says: `gronk: not found`. But if one of those *succeeds*, well, now the shell knows where `gronk` is, and can go straight there next time. That's the "hash" that speeds up later runs of the same program.

Comment: You can write your *own* commands and put them in a directory that you add to your `$PATH`, and now you can run your own commands too. I have two such directories in mine: one for binaries (which have to be compiled for each machine architecture, e.g., x86 vs arm or powerpc) and one for scripts (which work the same on all machines). The binary one is `$HOME/bin.$arch` where `$HOME` is a shell+env variable, and `$arch` is a shell variable I set myself. The scripts one is `$HOME/scripts`. I can use the same home directory on different machines, this way.

Comment: The hash trick gets important when $PATH gets very long. Mine has 11 elements on one machine and 16 on another...